# I can't find any documentation for chrome.favicon API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm upgrading my extensions to manifest v3 however the API documentation and migration documentation is less than useful in most cases. Yet the manifest v3 have been enabled on Chrome version 88.

Can someone provide the chrome.favicon API documentation, please?

Comment: There's no such API yet as can be verified by checking chromium source code so it's something that will be implemented in the future. You can click the star in https://crbug.com/104102 to be notified of development progress.

Comment: "chrome://favicon/" doesn't work with manifest v3 so I assumed the API was implemented but not documented.

Comment: ManifestV3 will take a year to have all the omissions and problems addressed so there's no rush.

Comment: Oh. Then I misunderstood their release blog post. I thought this were the grace period that allowed devs to update their extensions. I apologize.
It's bewildering why they push the manifest v3 code to the stable fork before they have the required documentation. More incompetence from the Chrome dev team.

Comment: Github example for V3 is up: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/api/favicon

Answer (score 1):

According to the document "coming soon".^^

Answer (score 0):

the [new API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/favicon/) to fetch the favicon has provided

---

they said to build the new API [this api](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104102), but it seems like they forget to build it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30567107)

Answer (score 0):

The New favicon API is now available. You can have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/favicon/).